# How can I create a new variable using conditions applied to several columns of data?

Tags: r, function, na, recode

I am a R novice currently experiencing some difficulty with my code. Essentially, I have several variables in a dataset that contain information on which types of activities an individual frequently participates in (e.g. 1 = reading, 2 = arts and crafts, 3 = gardening, ect..).

Some simulated data:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011),
                    orig_1 = c('-7', '2','1','1','NA','2', '3','NA','NA','2', '2'),
                    orig_2 = c('1','1','2','1','3','2', '2', '3','NA','2', '2'),
                    orig_3 = c('-7','3','NA','1','NA','2','NA','1','NA','2', '2'))
```

Based on these variables, I would like to create new variables that, for instance, reflects whether a person participates in a specific (e.g. 0 = no, 1 = yes). The first thing I have done is code values that correspond to "do not know" as NA:

```
#Recode variables
df$orig_1[df$orig_1==-7] <- NA

df$orig_2[df$orig_2==-7] <- NA

df$orig_3[df$orig_3==-7] <- NA
```

Then I have created my new 'activity' variables:

```
# create new activity variable
df$activity_1 <- NA
df$activity_2 <- NA
df$activity_3 <- NA
```

Next, I have adapted a function (kindly suggested by @Sonny) to search through the following columns and return a "1" (for those reporting to have participated in an activity) or otherwise a "0":

```
df$activity_1 <- na.omit(apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) {
  if(any(x %in% c(1))) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}))

df$activity_2 <- na.omit(apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) {
  if(any(x %in% c(2))) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}))

df$activity_3 <- na.omit(apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) {
  if(any(x %in% c(3))) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}))
```

This part does not work but the idea here was to introduce Na's to the new variables if all original variables were equivalent to "NA":

```
df$activity_1[df$orig_1==NA & df$orig_2==NA & df$orig_3==NA] <- NA
```

Ideally, the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
     ID orig_1 orig_2 orig_3 activity_1 activity_2 activity_3
1  1001      NA      1    NA          1          0          0
2  1002      2      1     NA          1          1          0
3  1003      1      2     NA          1          1          0
4  1004      1      1      1          1          0          0
5  1005     NA      3     NA          0          0          1
6  1006      2      2      2          0          1          0
7  1007      3      2     NA          0          1          1
8  1008     NA     NA      1          1          0          0
9  1009     NA     NA     NA          NA         NA         NA
10 1010      2      2      2          0          1          0
11 1011      2      2      2          0          1          0
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions you may have on improving this code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make true `NA`s. You're doing `'NA'` which is a string and different from `NA`. We can fix this like so:

```
df[df == "NA"] <- NA
```

Then we could look in an `apply` where all columns `2:4` are `NA` and set the `activity_*` columns accordingly.

```
df[apply(df[2:4], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))), 5:7] <- NA
```

Or vectorized, as *@akrun* suggested:

```
df[!rowSums(!is.na(df[2:4])), 5:7] <- NA
```

```
df
#      ID orig_1 orig_2 orig_3 activity_1 activity_2 activity_3
# 1  1001     -7      1     -7          1          0          0
# 2  1002      2      1      3          1          1          1
# 3  1003      1      2   <NA>          1          1          0
# 4  1004      1      1      1          1          0          0
# 5  1005   <NA>      3   <NA>          0          0          1
# 6  1006      2      2      2          0          1          0
# 7  1007      3      2   <NA>          0          1          1
# 8  1008   <NA>      3      1          1          0          1
# 9  1009   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         NA         NA         NA
# 10 1010      2      2      2          0          1          0
# 11 1011      2      2      2          0          1          0
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 
1008, 1009, 1010, 1011), orig_1 = structure(c(NA, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("-7", "1", "2", "3", 
"NA"), class = "factor"), orig_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    orig_3 = structure(c(NA, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L), .Label = c("-7", "1", "2", "3", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    activity_1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), activity_2 = c(0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), activity_3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "orig_1", "orig_2", 
"orig_3", "activity_1", "activity_2", "activity_3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Great "logicalization" with `!`,  thanks @akrun, added to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
#df[df == "NA"] <- NA
df %>%   mutate(activity_1 = case_when( orig_1 == 1 | orig_2 == 1 | orig_3 == 1 ~ 1,
                                 TRUE ~ 0),
         activity_2 = case_when( orig_1 == 2 | orig_2 == 2 | orig_3 == 2 ~ 1,
                                 TRUE ~ 0),
         activity_3 = case_when( orig_1 == 3 | orig_2 == 3 | orig_3 == 3 ~ 1,
                                 TRUE ~ 0)) %>%

  #mutate_at(.vars = c(5:7), list(~ifelse(is.na(orig_1) & is.na(orig_2) &is.na(orig_3), NA, .)))

  mutate_at(.vars = c(5:7), list(~ifelse(orig_1 =="NA" & orig_2  =="NA" & orig_3  =="NA", NA, .)))
```

or

```
df %>% na_if(.,"NA") %>% #na_if replaces specified value (this case "NA") to NA
                mutate(activity_1 = case_when( orig_1 == 1 | orig_2 == 1 | orig_3 == 1 ~ 1,
                                        TRUE ~ 0),
                activity_2 = case_when( orig_1 == 2 | orig_2 == 2 | orig_3 == 2 ~ 1,
                                        TRUE ~ 0),
                activity_3 = case_when( orig_1 == 3 | orig_2 == 3 | orig_3 == 3 ~ 1,
                                        TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = c(5:7), list(~ifelse(is.na(orig_1) & is.na(orig_2) &is.na(orig_3), NA, .)))    

          ID orig_1 orig_2 orig_3 activity_1 activity_2 activity_3
1  1001     -7      1     -7          1          0          0
2  1002      2      1      3          1          1          1
3  1003      1      2     NA          1          1          0
4  1004      1      1      1          1          0          0
5  1005     NA      3     NA          0          0          1
6  1006      2      2      2          0          1          0
7  1007      3      2     NA          0          1          1
8  1008     NA      3      1          1          0          1
9  1009     NA     NA     NA         NA         NA         NA
10 1010      2      2      2          0          1          0
11 1011      2      2      2          0          1          0
>
```

Comment: sorry just for completion sake added to deal with NAs per @ jay.sf to change all character NAs prior or to leave as characters ...